# При смене направления объекта ( в какую сторону смотрит) не меняется направление движения

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Beard : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float force = 1000f;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float movespeed = 15f;
        float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.Translate(new Vector2(move * movespeed * Time.deltaTime, 0));

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.up * force);
        }

        if (move > 0)
        {
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
        }
        if (move < 0)
        {
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Если закомментить эту часть кода, то перемещение работает правильно.

```
if (move > 0)
        {
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
        }
        if (move < 0)
        {
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
        }
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Если задать перемещение с помощью ```rb.velocity```, то всё норм. В чём отличие?

Comment: Ну velocity добавляет скорость, то есть объект движется по направлению вектора скорости, а Translate двигает в определенную сторону.

Comment: У них нет отличий, это вообще разные вещи. В [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html) всё написано русским по серому.

Comment: Ну... там белый фон. К тому же не все по русски:)